# building json for an array of serialized objects

Tags: c#, json

I'm using JavascriptSerializer with a custom JavascriptConverter to serialize two objects and return an array of these objects. I'm creating the array using Stringbuilder somewhat like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
TheSerializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new MyConverter()});

TheStringBuilder.Append("[");
TheStringBuilder.Append(TheSerializer.Serialize(FirstObject));
TheStringBuilder.Append("],[");
TheStringBuilder.Append(TheSerializer.Serialize(SecondObject));
TheStringBuilder.Append("]");

TheJsonToClient = TheStringBuilder.ToString();
```

The serialization and the custom converter work fine because in other parts of the code I'm using those and on the client JSON.parse work well for these objects.

The problem is that when I'm reading the return string and calling `JSON.parse` on it, the deserialization fails on the client with an `Unexpected Token` error during the parsing.

What am I doing wrong with the encoding that could cause this error when I'm deserializing the arrray?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong` you are using StringBuilder to form a json.

Comment: @L.B There is nothing wrong with building JSON by hand, as long as you do it correctly.

Comment: @cdhowie That's the problem. It is open to many bugs (as in question)

Comment: @L.B Everything you can possibly do in software development is open to bugs.  "Don't ever do X" assumes that you know all of the possible situations in which doing X might work, and that you know that it is a bad idea in all of them.  There are exceptions to every rule.

Comment: @cdhowie are you bored and and looking for someone to talk to?

Comment: @L.B: I fixed the code by removing the StringBuilder and implementing cdhowie's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
TheStringBuilder.Append("],[");
```

Should read:

```
TheStringBuilder.Append(",");
```

Valid JSON would be something like `[1,2]` -- your code is generating `[1],[2]`, which is invalid JSON.

Also, have you considered trying this instead of building the JSON array by hand?

```
TheSerializer.Serialize(new[] { FirstObject, SecondObject });
```

Comment: ok, thanks! The suggestion you provided is actually better than fixing my code!